# Add item to array Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a table with these fields: `product`, `lot`, `input1`, `input2`. You can clone a line, and you can add a new line.

What I want to do is that for each row you can add a new Lot created by a "number" and by "id" that user write in the input field under the Select `lot`. And I *wanted* that the script add the new Lot in the json data and the `lot` 's option list.

This is the function for **add** that I tried to do:

```
$scope.addLot = function() {
    var inWhichProduct = row.selectedProduct;
    var newArray = {
        "number": row.newLot.value,
        "id": row.newLot.id
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.items[i].selectedProduct === inWhichProduct) {
            $scope.items[i].selectedLot.push(newArray);
        }
    }
};
```

-->> [**THIS**](http://plnkr.co/edit/y9XDz9oF0vI7Dw08i4vH?p=preview)  <<--   is the full code.

Can you help me?

Comment: You should be more specific, try to reduce the Plunker next time only to show the exact problem.
It's not clear what's wrong in code. you should explain what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I have a table. The first <select> is made by some value of json. The second <select> is empty and fill with a sub-array of the first selected item. So, you choose a Product, and then you have - in the second selection - the list of the Lots of that Product. And for now, all works fine. But I have a problem. Because now, what I want to do, is that for each row you can add a Lot formed by a "number" and by "id" that user write in the input field under the Select Lot. And I wanted that the script add the new Lot in the json data, and then update the select adding the lot.

Comment: I hope it was clear enought. Do you some suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a little too broad to answer on Stack Overflow, but here's an attempt:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="lot in lots">
            <td>{{ lot.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ lot.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>name:</p> <input type="text" ng-model="inputName">
    <p>id:</p> <input type="text" ng-model="inputId">
    <button ng-click="addLotButton(inputId, inputName)">Add</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.lots = [{
            name: "test",
            id: 1
        },

        {
            name: "test2",
            id: 2
        }

        ];

        $scope.addLot = function(lotId, lotName) {
            var newLotObject = {
                name: lotName,
                id: lotId
            };

            $scope.lots.push(newLotObject);
        };

        $scope.addLotButton = function(id, name) {
            $scope.addLot(id, name);
        };

        $scope.addLot(3, "Another test");


    });
</script>
```

Basically this code just takes some input and adds an object to the scope for that input. The table is created using an ng-repeat of this data. It's not great code at all but it's just a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

The push method adds *newArray* to selectedLot array. It's not working on the JSON data but on arrays. If you want to have the JSON, you can give a try to :

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

It will create a JSON string based on the parameter

Maybe you should try to structure your data to make lots as properties of products.

```
{
    products: [
        {id: 1, lots: [{id:1}, {id:2}]},
        {id: 2, lots: [{id:1}, {id:2}]}
    ]
}
```

To add a lot to a product :

```
product = products[0];
product.lots.push(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the fallowing:

html:

```
   <button ng-click="addLot(row.selectedProduct.id,row.newLot.value,row.newLot.id)">Add</button>
```

js:

```
  $scope.addLot = function(id,val,lotId) { 
        // console.log(id);
        var inWhichProduct = id;
        var newArray = { "value": val, "id": lotId };
       //console.log($scope.items)
        angular.forEach($scope.items,function(v,i){
          if($scope.items[i].id == id )
          {
            $scope.items[i].lots.push(newArray);
            console.log($scope.items[i].lots);
          }
        });




  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/W8eche8eIEUuDBsRpLse?p=preview

Comment: you answer is perfect, but doesn't work when I put the "New Lot" fiedls in a modal window. Why? see at last forked: http://plnkr.co/edit/d592JsS6VznPmzcEyDJm?p=preview

Comment: I don't know there isn't shown, but in my local file when i press Confirm, in the console I see: "undefined", and then a new line written: Array [ Object, Obejct, Object, Obejct, Object, Obejct, Object, Obejct, Object, ..... ] ....it's like there aren't linked..but how can i do this?

Comment: whan you put in a modal you don't have acces to your product id

Comment: yes this is the problem!! How can I do? I've searched on google but I can't find a solution to pass the product-id